# How to fix nodes when plotting a subset over a complete network using igraph R

Tags: r, networking, overlay, visualization, igraph

I have a problem concerning network visualization using the igraph package provided in R.

Assume that you have a certain network, which contains the total sample of nodes and edges. Let me name this network netX:

```
netX <- structure(c(1, 0.48275862, 0.51724138, 0.48275862, 0.27906977, 
0.06896552, 0.34482759, 0.32352941, 0.06896552, 0.34482759, 0.03448276, 
0.06896552, 0.20689655, 0.17241379, 0.17241379, 0, 0.23333333, 
0.27586207, 0.21621622, 0.24137931, 0.48275862, 1, 0.4137931, 
0.35714286, 0.25581395, 0.25, 0.25, 0.38235294, 0.07142857, 0.28571429, 
0.21428571, 0.28571429, 0.10714286, 0.07142857, 0.21428571, 0.03571429, 
0.2, 0.32142857, 0.16216216, 0.25, 0.51724138, 0.4137931, 1, 
0.5862069, 0.34883721, 0.06896552, 0.20689655, 0.32352941, 0, 
0.27586207, 0.10344828, 0.06896552, 0.10344828, 0.10344828, 0.13793103, 
0, 0.36666667, 0.24137931, 0.21621622, 0.17241379, 0.48275862, 
0.35714286, 0.5862069, 1, 0.23255814, 0.11538462, 0.23076923, 
0.26470588, 0, 0.30769231, 0.11538462, 0.07692308, 0.11538462, 
0.15384615, 0.25, 0.03846154, 0.26666667, 0.21428571, 0.21621622, 
0.14285714, 0.27906977, 0.25581395, 0.34883721, 0.23255814, 1, 
0.18604651, 0.11627907, 0.18604651, 0, 0.18604651, 0.25581395, 
0.25581395, 0.27906977, 0.13953488, 0.20930233, 0.04651163, 0.23255814, 
0.34883721, 0.25581395, 0.30232558, 0.06896552, 0.25, 0.06896552, 
0.11538462, 0.18604651, 1, 0.13043478, 0.32352941, 0, 0.25, 0.34782609, 
0.34782609, 0.16666667, 0.13043478, 0.35714286, 0.17391304, 0.16666667, 
0.28571429, 0.16216216, 0.35714286, 0.34482759, 0.25, 0.20689655, 
0.23076923, 0.11627907, 0.13043478, 1, 0.23529412, 0, 0.29166667, 
0.04347826, 0.09090909, 0.16666667, 0.33333333, 0.21428571, 0.06666667, 
0.23333333, 0.17857143, 0.16216216, 0.21428571, 0.32352941, 0.38235294, 
0.32352941, 0.26470588, 0.18604651, 0.32352941, 0.23529412, 1, 
0.08823529, 0.29411765, 0.23529412, 0.17647059, 0.11764706, 0.14705882, 
0.26470588, 0.08823529, 0.26470588, 0.26470588, 0.32432432, 0.23529412, 
0.06896552, 0.07142857, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.08823529, 1, 0.04166667, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.03571429, 0, 0, 0, 0.05405405, 0.03571429, 0.34482759, 
0.28571429, 0.27586207, 0.30769231, 0.18604651, 0.25, 0.29166667, 
0.29411765, 0.04166667, 1, 0.25, 0.25, 0.20833333, 0.125, 0.25, 
0.04166667, 0.23333333, 0.17857143, 0.16216216, 0.14285714, 0.03448276, 
0.21428571, 0.10344828, 0.11538462, 0.25581395, 0.34782609, 0.04347826, 
0.23529412, 0, 0.25, 1, 0.69565217, 0.125, 0.08695652, 0.17857143, 
0, 0.16666667, 0.32142857, 0.24324324, 0.25, 0.06896552, 0.28571429, 
0.06896552, 0.07692308, 0.25581395, 0.34782609, 0.09090909, 0.17647059, 
0, 0.25, 0.69565217, 1, 0.08333333, 0.09090909, 0.17857143, 0, 
0.2, 0.35714286, 0.18918919, 0.25, 0.20689655, 0.10714286, 0.10344828, 
0.11538462, 0.27906977, 0.16666667, 0.16666667, 0.11764706, 0, 
0.20833333, 0.125, 0.08333333, 1, 0.20833333, 0.25, 0.04166667, 
0.2, 0.17857143, 0.27027027, 0.28571429, 0.17241379, 0.07142857, 
0.10344828, 0.15384615, 0.13953488, 0.13043478, 0.33333333, 0.14705882, 
0, 0.125, 0.08695652, 0.09090909, 0.20833333, 1, 0.21428571, 
0.15384615, 0.2, 0.25, 0.16216216, 0.14285714, 0.17241379, 0.21428571, 
0.13793103, 0.25, 0.20930233, 0.35714286, 0.21428571, 0.26470588, 
0.03571429, 0.25, 0.17857143, 0.17857143, 0.25, 0.21428571, 1, 
0.10714286, 0.26666667, 0.32142857, 0.37837838, 0.46428571, 0, 
0.03571429, 0, 0.03846154, 0.04651163, 0.17391304, 0.06666667, 
0.08823529, 0, 0.04166667, 0, 0, 0.04166667, 0.15384615, 0.10714286, 
1, 0.16666667, 0.10714286, 0.05405405, 0.07142857, 0.2333333, 
0.2, 0.3666667, 0.2666667, 0.2325581, 0.1666667, 0.2333333, 0.2647059, 
0, 0.2333333, 0.1666667, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2666667, 0.1666667, 
1, 0.4, 0.2972973, 0.3, 0.2758621, 0.3214286, 0.2413793, 0.2142857, 
0.3488372, 0.2857143, 0.1785714, 0.2647059, 0, 0.1785714, 0.3214286, 
0.3571429, 0.1785714, 0.25, 0.3214286, 0.1071429, 0.4, 1, 0.1891892, 
0.4285714, 0.21621622, 0.16216216, 0.21621622, 0.21621622, 0.25581395, 
0.16216216, 0.16216216, 0.32432432, 0.05405405, 0.16216216, 0.24324324, 
0.18918919, 0.27027027, 0.16216216, 0.37837838, 0.05405405, 0.2972973, 
0.18918919, 1, 0.43243243, 0.24137931, 0.25, 0.17241379, 0.14285714, 
0.30232558, 0.35714286, 0.21428571, 0.23529412, 0.03571429, 0.14285714, 
0.25, 0.25, 0.28571429, 0.14285714, 0.46428571, 0.07142857, 0.3, 
0.42857143, 0.43243243, 1), .Dim = c(20L, 20L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", 
    "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t"), c("a", "b", 
    "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", 
    "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t")))
```

Assume further that I have a certain subset of this network, which I call netY:

```
sub_netX <- c("a", "d", "h", "l", "o")
netY <- netX[sub_netX,sub_netX]

netY
           a          d         h          l         o
a 1.00000000 0.48275862 0.3235294 0.06896552 0.1724138
d 0.48275862 1.00000000 0.2647059 0.07692308 0.2500000
h 0.32352941 0.26470588 1.0000000 0.17647059 0.2647059
l 0.06896552 0.07692308 0.1764706 1.00000000 0.1785714
o 0.17241379 0.25000000 0.2647059 0.17857143 1.0000000
```

My target is to overlay both networks, so that one can see the complete network netX in the background and the subset netY in the forground. But first of all we need to load the igraph package, determine the layout of the potential plot and store the X and Y coordinates.

```
library(igraph)

inetX <- graph.adjacency(netX, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE, diag=F)
inetY <- graph.adjacency(netY, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE, diag=F)

lay <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(inetX)
V(inetX)$x <- lay[, 1]
V(inetX)$y <- lay[, 2]
```

Furthermore I think it is not really neccessary to get the index of the subset, but it can be handy for indexing later:

```
idx <- which(V(inetX)$name %in% c("a", "d", "h", "l", "o"))
```

We can also store the node colors upfront:

```
V(inetX)$color <- "grey"
V(inetY)$color <- "red"
```

But what is happening when I try to overlay both networks in a simple plot is that the nodes of the subset inetY are not exactly displayed at the position of the same nodes of inetX, despite fixed coordinates.

```
plot.igraph(inetX, layout = lay, vertex.size = 7)
plot.igraph(inetY, layout = lay[idx,], vertex.size = 4, add = TRUE)
```

I can't upload images, as my reputation is too low, but I hope that you can follow the steps on your machines.

My question to you all is, why does this happen? What am I doing wrong in the sense of how can I fix node coordinates when I overlay two networks?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I tweaked your netX matrix to make it easier for others to read in the data - you can get the structure by using `dput(netX)`. Hope this is ok

Comment: Yes, that's totally ok. Thanks for this hint. I didn't know so far

Comment: Could you just plot one graph, netX, and colour the five nodes differently from the others

Comment: Yes your're right. That's possible and I did this. However, I have not only one subset of netX but several and I thought it might be easier to handle the data if I could plot them simply on top of each other and change style separately. But maybe that's not possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is that igraph plotting functions rescale the layout to `[-1,1] x [-1,1]` by default. You can use the `rescale=FALSE` argument to `plot()` and then no rescaling is performed.

Note that in this case you'll need to set the limits of the plot by hand, by setting `xlim` and `ylim`:

```
xlim <- range(lay[,1])
ylim <- range(lay[,2])
plot.igraph(inetX, layout = lay, vertex.size = 20, 
            xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, rescale = FALSE)
plot.igraph(inetY, layout = lay[idx,], vertex.size = 14, 
            add = TRUE, rescale = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Gabor. Your answer is straighforward and works perfectly fine. You saved me a lot of time! If I could upgrade your advice, I would ;)

Comment: @Gabor Csardi I have a stimilat but slightly different problem... Do you mind having a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73352806/visualize-timely-disaggregated-network-and-fix-nodes-position-with-igraph-r