# Plot two igraph networks using the same coordinates and same placement in the plot frame

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I am trying to plot a network that changes in time. The network starts with a certain number of nodes and edges and each time step some of the nodes and edges are removed.

I want to be able to plot the network so that the nodes are in the same place in each. However when I try this. sometimes the nodes shift position in the plot frame even if the relation to each other is the same.

I am making the network change into a gif so even small changes are annoying. I think the change may occur when a large fraction of the nodes are removed but I am not sure.

The code below illustrates this using an ER graph.

```
library(igraph); library(dplyr)

#generate random graph
set.seed(500)
RandomGraph <- sample_gnm(1000, 2500)

#name nodes
V(RandomGraph)$name <- paste0("Node", 1:1000)

#Get the coordinates of the Nodes
Coords <- layout_with_fr(RandomGraph) %>% 
  as_tibble %>%
    bind_cols(data_frame(names = names(V(RandomGraph))))

#Delete random vertices
deletevertex <-sample( V(RandomGraph)$name, 400)

RandomGraph2 <-delete.vertices(RandomGraph, deletevertex)

#get the coordinates of the remaining Nodes
  NetCoords <- data_frame(names = names(V(RandomGraph2))) %>%
    left_join(Coords, by= "names")

#plot both graphs

RandomGraph%>% 
  plot(.,vertex.size=.8, edge.arrow.size=.4, vertex.label = NA, layout = as.matrix(Coords[,1:2]))

RandomGraph2%>% 
  plot(.,vertex.size=.8, edge.arrow.size=.4, vertex.label = NA, layout = as.matrix(NetCoords[,2:3]))

#They nodes have the same relationship to each other but are not laid out in the same position in the frame
```

As you can see the plots have placed nodes in the same place relative to each other but not relative to the frame.

How can I have the plot position fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix nodes when plotting a subset over a complete network using igraph R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301992/how-to-fix-nodes-when-plotting-a-subset-over-a-complete-network-using-igraph-r) . Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329309/plot-vertices-at-the-same-position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plot.igraph rescales each axis by default (from -1 to +1 on both x and y).

You just need to turn that off: `rescale = F` and then explicitly set appropriate `xlim` and `ylim` values.

For your example code..

```
RandomGraph%>% 
  plot(.,vertex.size=.8, edge.arrow.size=.4, vertex.label = NA, layout = as.matrix(Coords[,1:2]),rescale=F,xlim=c(-25,30),ylim=c(-20,35))

RandomGraph2%>% 
  plot(.,vertex.size=.8, edge.arrow.size=.4, vertex.label = NA, layout = as.matrix(NetCoords[,2:3]),rescale=F,xlim=c(-25,30),ylim=c(-20,35))
```

Comment: Thanks I controlled the xlim/ylim using the below, This allowed me to use the solution across graph iterations.

xlim = c(min(Coords[,1]), max(Coords[,1]))

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that

```
identical(range(Coords[1]), range(NetCoords[2]))
# [1] FALSE
```

Since igraph normalizes the coordinates on a range between -1 and 1 before plotting, this leads to slightly different coordinates for `NetCoords` compared to `Coords`. I'd just **calculate the normalized coordinates for all nodes beforehand**:

```
coords_rescaled <- sapply(Coords[-3], function(x) -1+((x-min(x))*2)/diff(range(x)))
rownames(coords_rescaled) <- Coords$names
```

And then assign the normalized coordinates (or the required subset) and set `rescale=FALSE` (as @jul) already suggested:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2), mar=c(1,.5,1,.5))
RandomGraph%>% 
  plot(.,edge.arrow.size=.4, layout = coords_rescaled, rescale=F);box()
RandomGraph2%>% 
  plot(.,edge.arrow.size=.4, layout = coords_rescaled[NetCoords$names, ], rescale=F);box()
```