# igraph: How to fix node position when drawing incrementally growing subgraphs of the same graph

Tags: python, igraph, graph-drawing

I have a graph where I have previously precomputed the positions of the nodes by running ForceAtlas2 in Gephi and then I attempt to draw with `ìgraph` in python. Each node has a `date` attribute so I iterate over all years, compute the corresponding subgraphs and draw them to create an animation effect.

However as nodes keep being added to the graph, the previous nodes don't necessarily keep their old positions, similarly to what is described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301992/how-to-fix-nodes-when-plotting-a-subset-over-a-complete-network-using-igraph-r)

My code is as follows:

```
colors = [color_list[int(g.vs[v]["Modularity Class"])] for v in range(0, len(g.vs))]
label_sizes = [sz / 4.0 for sz in g.vs["size"]]

nodes_in_years = defaultdict(list) # keeps a list of nodes per year
for v in g.vs:
    year = int(v["date"][:4]) # convert the first 4 digits of the date to year
    nodes_in_years[year].append(v)

nodes_incremental = []
for y, nodes in nodes_in_years.items():
    nodes_incremental += nodes
    h = g.subgraph(nodes_incremental)

    plot(h, "graph-igraph%d.png"%y,
         bbox=(640,480),
         vertex_color=colors,
         vertex_label_size=label_sizes,
         keep_aspect_ratio=False,
          )
```

The following are two consecutive snapshots.
[image: graph 2001]
[image: graph 2002]

In the second snapshot nodes are slightly "squeezed" as more nodes are added to the left.

How can I keep the nodes at fixed positions? I tried with `xlim` setting and `ylim` but I might not be setting the values right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xlim` and `ylim` are for the R interface of igraph; they have no effect in Python. The usual trick to employ is to find the minimum and maximum X and Y coordinates across all snapshots, and then place two fake vertices (with their `shape` attribute set to `None`) in the upper left and lower right corners of the layout. Make sure that you include these fake vertices in all snapshots with the same coordinates - this will ensure that the layouts are scaled exactly the same way in each snapshot to fit the bounding box that you specify.

If you did not use the `shape` attribute with your current layout, note that adding a `shape` attribute to the fake vertices will also add the `shape` attribute (with the default value of `None`) to the "real" vertices, so you should manually set the `shape` attribute of all vertices except the two fake ones to `"circle"`.

Comment: Thank you very much Tamas! It should have occurred to me, nice trick! Also note another way to make the artificial nodes, not to display was to set the `size` attribute to 0.0